# Call js file in angular directive using grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs

I wrote a directive which work great before using the `grunt build` command. Indeed I have this initialization below that is not working anymore as the path to the library is not correct after build :

```
element.intlTelInput({
            validationScript: "bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/isValidNumber.js",
            preferredCountries: ['ch', 'fr']
        });
```

Is it possible to have a relative path that would work in both app and dist (after grunt build) context or something else like that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grunt-ng-constant, with two configurations one for local environment and other with production environment, and in the build task add the production ngconstant before all process, example:

```
ngconstant: {
            options: {
                dest: 'app/scripts/configuration.js',
                name: 'configuration'
            },
            local: {
                constants: {
                    'validationScript': 'bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/isValidNumber.js',
                }
            },
            dist:{
                constants: {
                   'validationScript': 'prodPathFile',
                }
            }
        },


grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'ngconstant:dist',
        'other_tasks'
    ]);
```

Only need configuration module to your angular app, and use the constant validationScript in your directive, example:

```
app.directive('yourdirective', ['validationScript', function(validationScript) {
  return {
   link: function(scope, element) {
element.intlTelInput({
            validationScript: validationScript,
            preferredCountries: ['ch', 'fr']
        });   
       }
   }
}]);
```

Comment: I am giving it a try. But how do you define the use of 'local' or 'dist' constants? Do you use the constant as a regular angular one inside your directive?

Comment: ngconstant create a file with a new module and the respective variables inside. You need import this in your index.html, when you are working local execute grunt ngconstant:local and regenerate the file.

Comment: Thanks for the command ! But I can not find out how to use/inject it inside my directive...

Comment: Edit the answer to add an example of a directive with the constant added